# Como generar un video de varios video clip conffmpeg

Tags: php, video

Estoy tratando de generar un video que contenga una serie de videos, para esto uso ffmpeg con php, esto me lo ejecuta bien a la hora de hacer pruebas simples, pero al momento de hacer lo que realmente necesito no lo hace, aqui lo que estoy haciendo:

Codigo php:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('ffmpeg.exe');
    shell_exec('ffmpeg -f concat -i ruta.txt -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4');
    echo 'ok';
?>
```

El archivo ruta:

```
file './Video/Video_01.mp4'
duration 3
file './Video/Video_02.mp4'
duration 3
file './Video/Video_03.mp4'
duration 2
file './Video/Video_03.mp4'
duration 3
```

Hasta donde tengo entendió es de esta forma me tendría que agrupar todos los vídeos en uno solo, pero no hace nada ejecuta eso pero nada no hace nada, alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i ruta.txt -vf format=yuv420p video.mp4
```

Donde `ruta.txt`:

```
file './Video/Video_01.mp4'
duration 3
file './Video/Video_02.mp4'
duration 3
file './Video/Video_03.mp4'
duration 2
file './Video/Video_03.mp4'
duration 3
file './Video/Video_03.mp4'
```